# Suppose we have an empty alphabet Σ=∅, what are the possible languages of this alphabet?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, sets

Lets say the alphabet is **Σ=∅**,what are the possible languages of this alphabet?

According to my definitions:

- I know that an alphabet is a finite set of symbols **Σ**
- I know words is a set of all finite symbols consisting of letters from the alphabet (**Σ***) and an empty string part of all words **ε ∈ Σ***
- I know that a language is a subset of words and an empty set is a subset of the words **∅ ⊆ Σ***

All this is very confusing to me, and I am very unsure about what languages there are when we have an empty set for the alphabet.

Comment: It's important to understand the difference between a *word* (which is a sequence of symbols), a *language*, which is a set of words, and a set of languages. Those are three different things, which are not interchangeable. Also, always keep in mind the difference between the notions of *element* and *subset*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your list of properties already solves the problem. As $\varepsilon$ is an element of $\Sigma^*$ and we cannot have any longer word due to the lack of symbols, we have $\varnothing^*=\{\varepsilon\}$.

A language is a subset of $\varnothing^*$, and as $\varnothing^*$ has only one element, there are two possible languages.

Comment: So does that mean that the language (subsets of  ∅) is just {} and  ∅?